# Google sheets API batchGet doesnt have a valueRanges object

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

For the batchGet operation from the google sheets API documentation, I do not have the values retrieved from the sheet. There is no "valueRanges" key in the returned dict object from `sheets.spreadsheets.values().batchGet(spreadsheetId='ID').execute()`. Also the function does not take the range parameter. How do I read the values for a specific range using batchGet?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.